# How to make figure bigger than body column width in Quarto

Tags: r, quarto

According to the [Quarto docs](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/article-layout.html), the figure below should be screen-width but instead it is just positioned at the left-hand side of the screen. How can I make it bigger? Adding `#| layout-ncol: 1` doesn't help either.

[image: screenshot of html document]

````
---
title: "Test"
format: html
---

```{r}
#| column: screen
plot(pressure)
```
````

Answer (score 4):

The generated image is not big enough to fill the full screen. Try the `out-width` parameter to scale the image ([docs](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/cells/cells-knitr.html#figures)). For best results, choose a vector-graphic format to ensure smooth scaling of the image.

````markdown
```{r}
#| column: screen
#| out-width: 100%
#| fig-format: svg
plot(pressure)
```
````

Comment: Thanks! I assumed `out-width` would be adjusted automatically. The bigger image doesn't look as crisp anymore though, even when I increase `fig-dpi`. Do you know a workaround for this too?

Comment: @dufei I'd try with `#| fig-format: svg`

Comment: I tried but it doesn't change anything... the embedded image is still a png. What does work, however, is using the tried and tested knitr options: `knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev = "svglite")`. There should be a way to achieve this using Quarto options though, I think 

Comment: @dufei: which Quarto version is running on your system? I'm running 1.2, and Quarto does produce an SVG with the above.

Comment: Weird! My Quarto CLI version is 1.2.269

Comment: Weird indeed. That might be worth a separate question and/or bug report.

Comment: I'll file one, thanks for helping to narrow it down!